# How to create click event in TextBlock inside WPF ListBox and get its Tag

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, textblock

I have a `ListBox` which creates a `TextBlock` for every item in my `Dictionary` and I need to create a click event and have the possibility to get anything from the `TextBlock` (`Tag` in example).

Is this even possible? I found many similar questions, but nothing that would work for me.

My `ListBox`:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listbox">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Tag="{Binding Path=Key}"
                           Text="{Binding Path=Value.ImieNazwisko}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simplify things lets say your dictionary is some thing like this :

```
public Dictionary<string,MyItem> MyDictionary { get; set; }
```

and your model :

```
public class MyItem
    {
        public string ImieNazwisko { get; set; }    
    }
```

and you set the `ListBox` `ItemSource` from the code behind like this :

```
InitializeComponent();

   MyDictionary = new Dictionary<string, MyItem>()
            {
                {"key1",new MyItem() {ImieNazwisko = "one"} },
                {"key2",new MyItem() {ImieNazwisko = "two"} }
            };
   Listbox.ItemsSource = MyDictionary;
```

You could simply handle the `MouseDown` event and retrieve the `Tag` property from the sender:

```
 <ListBox x:Name="Listbox" Margin="225,0,0,0" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Tag="{Binding Path=Key}" Text="{Binding Path=Value.ImieNazwisko}" MouseDown="UIElement_OnMouseDown"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

the handler

```
 private void UIElement_OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var tag=(sender as TextBlock).Tag;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked well. OnMouseDown is working slightly better tho.